# Which iPhone first supported JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, iphone

What version of the iPhone first supported JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All iPhones support JavaScript, try looking in your Safari settings.

Comment: Thank you. It was set off. Why would this be? Why would this be the default? I can't believe I just assumed it didn't support JavaScript all this time.

Comment: I'd accept your answer but I have to wait another 7 minutes... :S

Comment: Not sure why it would have come like that, maybe you or someone else accidently changed it?

Comment: no it wasn't changed. And this is my third iPhone 3G, and they all did this. EDIT: I can't know for sure if it wasn't changed, and the newer phones may have adopted the older phones' settings.

Comment: On older phones it could have been turned off to speed things up?